# Conference submission along with submitting to arXiv

Tags: publications, conference, arxiv

I am about to submit an article to an international conference (http://www.mldm.de/). I am thinking also to submit to arXiv as well. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Which journal/conference/publisher are you talking about? Please provide more precise information.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog http://www.mldm.de/. Edited the question to include the info.

Answer (score 2):

The way journals handle arXiv submissions depends entirely on the journal. Generally, it should be allowed since arXiv is a well established service. The only way to know for sure is to read the FAQ/Terms and Conditions or ask the publisher/editor.

Answer (score 1):

MLDM seems to publish the oral papers in LNCS, see [oral presentations](http://www.mldm.de/au_oral.php). LNCS allows preprints on arXiv: [LNCS on Sherpa/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/issn/0302-9743/). See also the [Springer Authors' Rights](https://www.springer.com/gp/open-access/authors-rights/self-archiving-policy/2124)

If you want to submit for a [poster presentation](http://www.mldm.de/au_poster.php), you should contact the editor. I couldn't find their policies so far.